# How do I display data from different tables with a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
**How to display the data as below with one query?** //Limit 2 and order by date and date2.

Data from tabel a

|  1 | aaa    | 2014-06-16 16:29:51

Data from tabel b

|  1 | aa2    | 2014-06-16 16:29:52
Table a

+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(3)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Table b

+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name2 | varchar(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date2 | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Data Table a

+----+--------+
| ID | name   | date
+----+--------+
|  1 | aaa    | 2014-06-16 16:29:51
|  3 | aba    | 2014-06-16 16:29:52
|  8 | id     | 2014-06-16 16:29:53
| 10 | idr    | 2014-06-16 16:29:55


Data Table b

+----+--------+
| ID | name2   | date2
+----+--------+
|  1 | aa2    | 2014-06-16 16:29:52
|  3 | a2a    | 2014-06-16 16:29:53
|  8 | id2    | 2014-06-16 16:29:53
| 10 | id2    | 2014-06-16 16:29:53

**How to display the data as below with one query?** //Limit 2 and order by date and date2.

Data from tabel a

|  1 | aaa    | 2014-06-16 16:29:51

Data from tabel b

|  1 | aa2    | 2014-06-16 16:29:52
```

Comment: Your questions is incomprehensible. what you need exactly? what you try?

Comment: `select * from tableA where id=1 union select * from tableB where id=1`   conceptually. Your results may vary

Comment: and how to apply sorting to order by and also restrictions on the amount shown with a limit so that the data can be displayed can be sequentially by date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you want something like:

```
(SELECT ID, name, date
    FROM TableA
    LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT ID, name2, date2
    FROM TableB
    LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: OUT ERROR "#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: Updated my answer. We'll just need to place each statement in parentheses.

Comment: and how if we want a different amount of its Select? example (select a, b from c) union (select a from d)? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Technically, that is a different question. `UNION` and such stuff need to have the same number of columns. In your example, you can use `NULL` to the second `SELECT` statement:  `(SELECT a, b FROM c) union (SELECT a, NULL FROM d)`. You can search the documentation for more information.